# Jest mocks in test util

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I'm using a __mocks__ folder to mock a node_module. Nice. 
Example to one of the mocks, that mock 'react-relay': https://gist.github.com/robrichard/ad838e599d828a89978f54faaa2070a8

The file is located as such `__mocks__/relay-react.js`,
the the mock with be used in my test when `jest.mock('react-relay)` is executed in the testfile.

However, I have many repos that need that same mock. Is it possible to put the mock in a `node_module`, so to streamline my tests and do not have to copy/paste the mock everywhere?

Comment: I haven't verified this and therefore won't post it as an answer, but at a minimum I believe you could make it an NPM package and create a `__mocks__/relay-react.js` that simply re-exports the shared value from `node_modules`. Something like `export { default } from "my-relay-react-mock"` or `export { relay as default } from "my-mocks"`. Then Jest wouldn't know the difference.

Comment: Yeah, that would also be possible, then I think this is a better solution: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2726#issuecomment-283100333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution so far (as described here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2726#issuecomment-283100333):

`testutils.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

exports.mockRelay = {
   createFragmentContainer: Component => props => <Component {...props} />,
   ...
   // all the named imports you want to mock
};
```

then in the testfile call

```
jest.mock('react-relay', () => require('util/testutils').mockRelay)
```